# SystemJS configuration to remove the check for index.js

Tags: angular, systemjs

I'm using the following SystemJS configuration to load an Angular2 app. When I load the app in the browser, I see that the SystemJS is adding index.js file to the path.

**Error:**

`system.src.js:1051 GET http://localhost:5000/lib/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js/index.js 404 (Not Found)`

**Configuration:**

`<script>
            window.onload = () => {
                System.defaultJSExtensions = true;
                System.config({
                    map: {
                        'rxjs': "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.0.7/rx.all.min.js",
                        '@@angular/core': '../../lib/@@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
                        '@@angular/common': '../../lib@@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
                        '@@angular/compiler': '../../lib/@@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
                        '@@angular/platform-browser': '../../lib/@@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
                        '@@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': '../../lib/@@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
                        '@@angular/http': '../../lib/@@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
                        '@@angular/router': '../../lib/@@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
                        '@@angular/forms': '../../lib/@@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
                        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': '../../lib/angular2-in-memory-web-api.js'
                    }
                });
                System.import("../app/app.module.js");
            }
</script>`

How can I configure SystemJS so I can load the following file:

**Expectation:**

Load `http://localhost:5000/lib/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js`

Comment: I don't find anything wrong in your SystemJS conf file. I think somewhere in your source code you use `import {something} from "@angular/platform-browser/index"` instead of `from "@angular/platform-browser"`. Note the `/index` at the end. Some IDE make incorrect auto imports sometimes.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? :-)

Comment: In my case it was because I updated one package using npm but not the other. And internally the other package was referencing the one I updated in an incorrect way. After updating the dependant package my issue was fixed (ngx-clipboard + ngx-window-token)